# If X and Y are perfectly correlated, what is the correlation of X+Y and X-Y?

Tags: probability, self-study, correlation, mathematical-statistics

I've started with thinking that if X and Y are perfectly correlated, then it is the same as looking at the correlation of Y and -Y (since the X provides no new information) and thus the correlation is -1.

Is this correct?

Comment: No reason why it can't be 1. Perfect correlation only says that Y=aX+b. If a is positive the correlation is 1 and it is -1 if a is negative. So what you need to do is find the correlation between (1+a)X+b with (1-a)X-b.

Comment: Your reasoning is flawed.

Comment: If a=1 the correlation is 0. But if a is not 1 it can be determined using my argument..

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ have a correlation coefficient  of $\rho$ then $X$ and $Y$ have a correlation coefficient  of $-\rho$.  If  $X$ and $Y$ are "perfectly correlated" (i.e. knowing $X=x$ you can be almost sure $Y=a+bx$ for some fixed $a,b$) then $\rho=+1$ or $-1$ but without more information you cannot tell which

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: *In general*, \begin{align}
\rho_{A,B} &= \frac{\operatorname{cov}(A,B)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(A)\operatorname{var}(B)}},\\
\operatorname{var}(X\pm Y)&= \operatorname{var}(X)+\operatorname{var}(Y)
\pm 2\operatorname{cov}(X,Y),\\
\text{and}\qquad\operatorname{cov}(X+Y,X-Y)&=\operatorname{var}(X)-\operatorname{var}(Y)\end{align} So, work out what $\rho_{X+Y,X-Y}$ is in general, and in the special case when $Y = aX+b$. You might be surprised at the result.

Comment: Using those properties, I came out to Var(X) - Var(Y) / 0? The denominator all cancelled out but that cannot be right as the denominator being 0 means that the correlation is undefined?

Comment: @JPMSpoof :  You would only get a denominator of zero from assuming equal variance.  Perfectly correlated is not the same as equal variance.  For instance, $Y = 5X$ yields perfect correlation with unequal variance.

Comment: No, the denominator is $\sigma_{X+Y}\sigma_{X-Y}$ which in the special case $\rho_{X,Y}=1$ makes $\sigma_{X\pm Y}= \sigma_{X}\pm \sigma_Y$ leading to $$\rho_{X+Y,X-Y}=\frac{\sigma_X^2-\sigma_Y^2}{(\sigma_X+\sigma_Y)(\sigma_X-\sigma_Y)}=1.$$

Comment: @EricTowers The answer I provided might give some insight into the denominator of zero issue, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

I'll treat this as [self-study](/questions/tagged/self-study), and I'd encourage you to read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and add the tag.

Your argument is already very good. Here are a few pointers. Feel free to write a comment so we can discuss and work towards a good answer.

- I assume you are looking at Pearson's correlation, right? (Does your argument work for other measures of correlation?)
- What does a perfect correlation mean *graphically*?
- What will $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ look like *graphically* if $X$ and $Y$ are perfectly Pearson-correlated?

Comment: Yes I am looking at Pearson's correlation. I know perfect correlation means the X-Y scatterplot follows a perfectly straight line, so now I imagine as X+Y increase, and X-Y decrease, the correlation will be negative

Comment: @Stephan I don't think the argument in the question is good at all. Consider X,Y bivariate normal with zero mean and Var(X) = $10^4$ Var(Y). Then X+Y is approximately X and X-Y is approximately X, and the OP's answer of -1 is as wrong as could be. Now consider zero means and Var(X) = Var(Y), in which case X-Y is always 0 and the correlation is undefined.

Comment: @Glen_b Please check your assertion that $X-Y$ is always $0$ when $X$ and $Y$ are perfectly correlated (cf. my comment to the OP in response to his comment on my answer).

Answer (score 1):

I see this already has an accepted answer, but I've always liked simulations more than equations, and this seemed like a fun question. I generated a variable $x$ from a distribution $N(0, 1)$ whose sample size $n$ was drawn from $U(100, 10000)$. To make $y$, I simply added a constant—drawn from $U(1, 100)$—to $x$. I then calculated the correlation between $X + Y$ and $X - Y$. I did this 10,000 times:

```
set.seed(1839)
cors <- sapply(1:10000, function(placeholder) {
  n <- runif(1, 100, 10000)
  b0 <- runif(1, 1, 100)
  x <- rnorm(n)
  y <- b0 + x
  cor(x + y, x - y)
})
```

You'll get a ton of warnings. I run `warnings()[1:5]` to get the first five:

```
Warning messages:
1: In cor(x + y, x - y) : the standard deviation is zero
2: In cor(x + y, x - y) : the standard deviation is zero
3: In cor(x + y, x - y) : the standard deviation is zero
4: In cor(x + y, x - y) : the standard deviation is zero
5: In cor(x + y, x - y) : the standard deviation is zero
```

We can still look at the histogram of correlations that *were* defined, calling `hist(cors[!is.na(cors)])`:

[image]

We can also look at how many of those simulations had the $Var(X - Y) = 0$:

```
set.seed(1839)
sd_is_zero <- sapply(1:10000, function(placeholder) {
  n <- runif(1, 100, 10000)
  b0 <- runif(1, 1, 100)
  x <- rnorm(n)
  y <- b0 + x
  ifelse(var(x - y) == 0, TRUE, FALSE)
})
```

Then we can call `prop.table(table(var_is_zero))` to see how many simulations generated $Var(X - Y) = 0$:

```
var_is_zero
 FALSE   TRUE 
0.1698 0.8302
```

But why were some defined and some undefined? Was it related to the sample size or was it related to the constant?

```
set.seed(1839)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10000, ncol = 3))
colnames(dat) <- c("var_is_zero", "n", "b0")
for (i in 1:10000) {
  n <- runif(1, 100, 10000)
  b0 <- runif(1, 1, 100)
  x <- rnorm(n)
  y <- b0 + x
  dat$var_is_zero[i] = ifelse(var(x - y) == 0, TRUE, FALSE)
  dat$n[i] = n
  dat$b0[i] = b0
}
```

We can now predict whether or not the variance was zero from the sample size, the constant, and the interaction, looking at the result with `summary(glm(var_is_zero ~ n * b0, data = dat, family = binomial()))`:

```
Call:
glm(formula = var_is_zero ~ n * b0, family = binomial(), data = dat)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.5154   0.1628   0.3039   0.5997   1.2894  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -2.613e-01  1.038e-01  -2.518   0.0118 *  
n           -2.114e-05  1.785e-05  -1.184   0.2362    
b0           5.323e-02  2.973e-03  17.907   <2e-16 ***
n:b0        -4.011e-07  4.968e-07  -0.807   0.4195    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 9111.4  on 9999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 7148.0  on 9996  degrees of freedom
AIC: 7156

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

It looks like the larger the intercept, the more likely the correlation is to be undefined.

Comment: By `y <- b0 + x`, you implicitly set $\sigma_Y=\sigma_X$, which is not implied by the condition. The result will be well-defined if you use $\sigma_X\neq\sigma_Y$.

Answer (score 1):

$X,Y$ perfectly correlate $\implies Cov(X,Y)=\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}$

$Cov(X+Y,X-Y)=Cov(X,X)-Cov(X,Y)+Cov(Y,X)-Cov(Y,Y)=Var(X)-Var(Y)$

$Var(X+Y)Var(X-Y)=[Var(X)+Var(Y)+2Cov(X,Y)][Var(X)+Var(Y)-2Cov(X,Y)]=[Var(X)+Var(Y)]^2-4Cov(X,Y)Cov(X,Y)=_{\rho_{X,Y}=1}=[Var(X)+Var(Y)]^2-4Var(X)Var(Y)=[Var(X)-Var(Y)]^2$

Hence, $\rho_{X+Y,X-Y}=Cov(X+Y,X-Y)/\sqrt{Var(X+Y)Var(X-Y)}=\pm1$.

As @whuber pointed out, when $Var(X)=Var(Y)$, $\rho_{X+Y,X-Y}$ is undefined.

`@Dilip Sarwate` has provided the answer in the comment to his post. I added some details.

Actually, if $Var(X)=Var(Y)$, given they are perfectly correlated, $Y=\pm X+b$, hence either $X+Y\equiv0$ or $X-Y\equiv0$. Therefore, $\rho=0$.

Comment: When $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\operatorname{Var}(Y)$, the denominator is $0$, whence the correlation is undefined in that case.

Comment: @whuber You are right, I forgot to mention this special case.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a linear function of $Y$ (definition of perfect correlation), then both $X-Y$ and $X+Y$ will be linear functions of $Y$, and therefore are linear functions of each other.

So, $X-Y$ and $X+Y$ are perfectly correlated.

Comment: Obviously if one or both of $X-Y$, $X+Y$ are constant, the answer is undefined. I assumed that's not the case while writing this answer.

Comment: I still on't see why it can't be -1.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I meant to say they were perfectly correlated. Thanks.